# Why can't I use universal reference in a way like `void(*func)(T&&)` and `for (T&& v : vec)`?

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I'm trying to use a universal reference in a callback function pointer and range-based `for` loop.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void PrintFunc(const T& value) {
    cout << value << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
void PrintFunc(T&& value)  {
    cout << value << "\n";
};

template<typename T>
void ForEach(const vector<T> vec, void(*func)(T&&)) {
    for (T&& val : vec)
    {
        func(std::forward(val));
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };
    ForEach<int>(v, PrintFunc<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

The code fails to compile:

> Error C2672 'forward': no matching overloaded function found
>
> Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &&'

I tried:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void ForEach(const vector<T> vec, void(*func)(const T&)) {
    for (const T& val : vec)
    {
        func(val);
    }
}
```

And this time the code compiles and works properly.

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a function that takes universal reference (not: its called a forwarding reference now).  A forwarding reference only exists as a template and a function pointer needs to point to a concrete function. `void(*func)(T&&)` is pointer to a function that takes an rvalue reference to a `T`.

Comment: `vec` is const, `T` is `int`, `val` is `const int&`, `T&& val` can't bind `const T`. What the error is talking about.

Comment: Basically because the `T&&` in `void(*func)(T&&)` is specifying the parameter of the function pointed to by the function pointer iinstead of specifying the second parameter of the function template `ForEach` itself. The type of the second parameter which is `func` is fixed(which is pointer to function). You can only pass pointer to functions to the second parameter. While Universal reference means it works with all arguments(which isn't the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forwarding references only arise when applied directly to a deduced template parameter.  That isn't the case with your function pointer.

Forwarding references aren't a "real" type.  They're a trick of the way template type deduction works.  The way forwarding references work is by deducing different types depending on the value category of the expression passed to them.

That is, given a function like:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T&& arg);
```

When you call `func(some_lvalue)`, where `some_lvalue` is an `int`, `T` gets deduced as `int&`.  That leaves `func`'s parameter as an `int& &&`.  Since you can't have references to references, the reference collapsing rules are applied, and the type of `arg` collapses to `int&`.

On the other hand, if you call `func(42)`, `T` gets deduced as `int`, leaving the type of `arg` as `int&&`.

---

For users not familiar with this stuff, see the old term "Universal References" coined by Scott Meyers [documented on isocpp](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and this video:
[C++ and Beyond 2012: Scott Meyers - Universal References in C++11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lq8PntQMV4).

Comment: For users not familiar with this stuff, Google for the old term "Universal References" coined by "Scott Meyers". See his article here https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers, video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lq8PntQMV4, and an absolute must read for all C++ developers (goes a long way to explain some issues I've never seen anywhere else!!), Chapter 1 ("Deducing Types") and Chapter 5 ("Rvalue References ...") in his book "Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve ...". Too bad he retired from C++ a number of years ago now (everyone's loss).

Comment: @Larry Thanks! Those are both very good links! Even though (I think) I know how it works, it's hard to stop listening to the talk by Scott Meyers. It's a very good "goto" whenever in doubt. It sort of hammers it in :-)